# readObject's influence on Serializability

Tags: java, deserialization

I have the classic situation where an object has been serialized to the database, and now when I try to deserialize it I get a `SerializationException: could not deserialize`.
Now my challenge is that this code is installed at various customers that potentially has different values of `serialVersionUID`, so overwriting this to the reported local class value is not the solution.

My question is if providing a readObject method will disable the serialVersionUID check, or if it still will be checked?

If the readObject disables the check of serialVersionUID, will this be enough then:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
}
```

Comment: `SerializationException: could not deserialize`. What's the *real* message?

Comment: Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: provisioning.command.SingleRequest; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 139725644440154843, local class serialVersionUID = 7153704688674318562

Comment: What I would do, is developing a migration tool that would use the existing version of the class of the customer to deserialize the object, and then re-serialize it using an open, versioned format such as JSON or XML. Then, once the data has been migrated, I would upgrade the version of the app and use a JSON or XML unmarshaller to read and write these objects. You might adopt the same strategy to save the data by copying it to a new class instance and serialize this new object, but you'll be bitten by the same problem later.

Comment: So readObject does not bypass serialVersionUID validation?